# How to install Scanjet 3200c on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: scanner

how to install Scanjet 3200c on ubuntu 12.10?

I am new to Ubuntu, so please help in details.
I  have done these all settings which is mentioned in one of Portuguese blog

1. I went into the BIOS and activated EPP mode for LPT1, `irq 7 0x378`. I guess I do not need these parameters but is recommended EPP mode.
2. I was in `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf` and commented the line where was the `umax` and uncommented the `umax_pp`.
3. insert my User group `lp`

Inspite of all I am unable to get through it.
The problem is, its not able to detect the scanning device.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is see whether or not HP Toolbox is installed or not.  To find out, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below:

```
hp-toolbox
```

If its not, you can install it, by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install hplip-gui
```

OR you can download it [here](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html).  And just follow the steps needed.

For more info you can check out the [Ubuntu Manuals](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man7/sane.7.html).

Comment: yeah hplip is install but still it is not working. It can't find the device, when I search particular port as well. Such as LPT for scanner and USB for printer. It is not able to search the device.

Comment: I did that but then it was not able to identify even printer (usb epson LX-300+) and scanner (lpt, hp 3200C). I guess there is problem with these ports but usb work well for pen-drive.